# Accessing Private data types

Tags: c++, struct

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
      private :
              typedef struct {
                      int a;
                      int j;
                      }type;
      public : 
             A(){};
            ~A(){};   
            void CreateInstance();               
        };

class B : public  A        
{
      private : 
              int d;
              int n;
      public :
             B(){};
            ~B(){};   
            void CreateInstance1();               

};


void A :: CreateInstance()
{ 
 A::type A;
 A.a = 0x10;     
 cout << " Val = " << A.a << endl;
}

void B :: CreateInstance1()
{ 
 // I want to create a Pointer/instance of structure in this function. Dont want to use Public method in Class A    
 A::type A;
 A.a = 0x10;     
 cout << " Val = " << A.a << endl;
}

int main()
{
 A obj;    
 obj.CreateInstance(); 
 B obj1;
 obj1.CreateInstance1();  
 cin.get();
 return 0;   
}
```

I am Looking forward to have some suggestion on this .

1. How can i create an instance the structure "type" in derived class.

Please let me know how i can use the "data type".

> Error : 'typedef struct A :: type A :: type' is Private.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Make it public or protected.

Comment: No its private.. we cannot change the access specifier

Comment: use `protected` instead of `private` for the declaration of `type`

Comment: Sorry I dont want to change access specifier... Is it possible or not

Comment: If it's private, why do you want one? Won't only the original class know how to consume it? If you can't change the specifier can you add a method to the original class to create one and return it? You may need to return it as a void* rather than a typed pointer.

Comment: No, it is not possible. That's what private is for.

Comment: @PragRao: The only options are to change the access specifier, or declare `B` a friend of `A`. By definition, you can only access private names within the class and its friends.

Comment: No !!! RUP !! i already created on instance i base class A .. i could have returned the instance or pointer of one. I just want to know whether i can use the "data type" on individual basis. i am stucked at one place. where i came accross such situation.

Comment: Hi Mike Seymour !! i tried making friend . but the data type didnt resolved . u can jus give a try if  i made some mistake in doing that.

Comment: *Side remarks:* Never use `using namespace std;` in a header. Don't use `typedef struct {..} name;` in C++, it's not necessary (just `struct name {..};`. If you inherit publicly (`class B : public A`), you'll probably want a virtual dtor in `A`.

Comment: Also what you're doing there in class `B` looks strange to me. If I call s.th. named `CreateInstance` with `B`, I'd never expect to get an instance of `A` as result, but a `B`. Maybe your're looking for copy constructors??

Answer (score 1):

Some possibilities:

- Change type to protected (but you say you can't).
- Use `friend class B;` in `A` (but then you could make the type protected too, I suppose).
- Ugly hack: re-declare the struct in `B`, creating identical type. Then use `memcpy` to copy between variables of the types if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use anything `private` from the base class, it is the rule of the language.

You can, however, use anything public or protected. In you case it, probably, will be sufficient to call the base class function `CreateInstance`

```
void B :: CreateInstance1()
{ 
    A::CreateInstance();
}
```

(In general it is better to keep cohesive naming: if applicable, consider declaring the function `CreateInstance` virtual and then rename `CreateInstance1` as `CreateInstance` to make it an overwrite of `A::CreateInstance`. It is not related to the question, though).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
      //woh that worked .. i did mistake here
      friend class B;
      private :
              typedef struct {
                      int a;
                      int j;
                      }type;
      public : 
             A(){};
            ~A(){};   
            void CreateInstance();               
        };

class B : public  A        
{
      private : 
              int d;
              int n;
      public :
             B(){};
            ~B(){};   
            void CreateInstance1();               

};


void A :: CreateInstance()
{ 
 A::type A;
 A.a = 0x10;     
 cout << " Val = " << A.a << endl;
}

void B :: CreateInstance1()
{ 
 // I want to create a Pointer/instance of structure in this function. Dont want to use Public method in Class A    
 A::type A;
 A.a = 0x10;     
 cout << " Val = " << A.a << endl;
}

int main()
{
 A obj;    
 obj.CreateInstance(); 
 B obj1;
 obj1.CreateInstance1();  
 cin.get();
 return 0;   
}
```

Comment: I don't think `friend` will solve your problems for the long term. I think you have some design flaws here, and should rethink why and how you use inheritance seriously.

Comment: Yeah can u suggest me some other. method because it will violate encapsulation

Comment: At least I don't get what's your point with the `CreateInstance()` method. Do you want to create a singleton or just provide a factory method. As it is, it's pretty unclear what you aim for. All in all I'd say there's no need for a `CreateInstance()` method, that's what constructors are for (and yes you can easily call constructors of your base classes as long these are at least protected) ...

Comment: All in all I think it's just a [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) you're asking for, need to know more about your use cases, and what you want to achieve with a comprehensible sample ...

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to work so badly, you can try something in these lines

Add a static method in A which creates object instances

static A::type GetTypeInstance();

```
A::type A :: GetTypeInstance()
{
  A::type lc_Atype;

  return tp;
}
```

So your `B::CreateInstance1` will be

```
void B :: CreateInstance1()
{ 
 auto A(A::GetTypeInstance());
 A.a = 0x10;     
 cout << " Val = " << A.a << endl;
}
```

Note that it creates unnecessary temporary objects if your compiler doesnt do RVO

Answer (score 0):

My prev answer uses C++11. Here's another way of doing this without auto.

```
class A {
      private :
              typedef struct {
                      int a;
                      int j;
                      }type;
      public : 
             A(){};
            ~A(){};   
            void CreateInstance();   
            typedef type AType;    **//Added this typedef**
        };
```

Change your B :: CreateInstance1 to

```
void B :: CreateInstance1()
{ 
 A::AType A;   **//Now this works**
 A.a = 0x10;     
 cout << " Val = " << A.a << endl;
}
```

This solution works because private hides the name and not the type as such. So we can can still expose type by wrapping it using public typedef.